# .Rprofile's search path is not the same as the default one

Tags: r, search-path, rprofile

Consider the two lines below:

```
Sys.setenv(R_IMPORT_PATH = "/path/to/my/r_import")
foo <- modules::import("foo")
```

If I execute this code from within an already-established interactive R session, it works fine.

But if I put the same two lines in my `.Rprofile` and start a new interactive R session, the `modules::import` line fails with

```
Error in module_init_files(module, module_path) : 
  could not find function "setNames"
```

If I then attempt the following fix/hack

```
Sys.setenv(R_IMPORT_PATH = "/path/to/my/r_import")
library(stats)
foo <- modules::import("foo")
```

...then the `modules::import` line still fails, but with the following

```
Error in lapply(x, f) : could not find function "lsf.str"
```

So the idea of patching the missing names seems like it will be an unmaintainable nightmare...

---

The crucial issue is this: It appears that the search path right after an interactive search session starts is different from the one that an `.Rprofile` script sees.

**Q1:** Is there a way that I can tell R to make the search path exactly as it will be when the first `>` prompt appears in the interactive session?

**Q2:** Alternatively, is there a way for the `.Rprofile` to schedule some code to run *after* the session's default search path is in place?

---

**NB:** Solutions like the following:

```
Sys.setenv(R_IMPORT_PATH = "/path/to/my/r_import")
library(stats)
library(utils)
foo <- modules::import("foo")
```

...are liable to break every time that the (third-party) `modules` package is modified.